# Fill up username/password from another HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to create an HTML form where users could enter information and fill up another form.

This is the page:

https://www.schoolbaseonline.biz/WebForms/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

Assuming that I have the information required via an HTML form, how do I get it to fill up the page and submit ?

Comment: How do I assign them to the second form without knowing what the value name is ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Do you use JavaScript, PHP or something else or only HTML?

Comment: Are you trying to prepopulate a form on your own site or is it a third party form?

Comment: We use this website to manage our school, however the login form is pretty standard and the software company isn't willing to customize it, since it's one login form for all their clients. What I wanted to do is create customized login form on our website (nicer page, easy url) and populate / submit their form.